# Bases with Negative Exponents in Exponential Functions

Tags: exponential-function

Is it correct to state that:
$$a^x=\frac{1}{a^{-x}}=\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-x}$$
and:
$$a^{-x}=\frac{1}{a^{x}}=\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{x}$$

Even though
$$\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-x}=\frac{1^{-x}}{a^{-x}}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{x}=\frac{1^x}{a^x}$$
?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true as for any finite value of $m$, we have $1^m=1$, so the latter reduces to
$$\left(\frac1a\right)^{-x}=\frac{1}{a^{-x}}=a^x$$
And by our original identity,
$$\left(\frac1a\right)^{-x}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac1a\right)^x}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^x}}=a^x$$
So, there is no contradiction.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)